# AEM Multimodule maven project build fails in Azure Pipeline alone

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines, aem, azure-pipelines-build-task, multi-module

com.projects.proj1
com.projects.proj2

we have two individual multimodule maven project.

-------------proj1-------------------

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.proj1</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.11.0</version>
    <description>proj1</description>
    
    <modules>
        <module>all</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>ui.frontend</module>
        <module>ui.apps</module>
        <module>ui.apps.structure</module>
        <module>ui.content</module> 
    </modules>
```

-------------proj2-------------------

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.proj2</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj2</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <description>proj2</description>
    
    <modules>
        <module>all</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>ui.frontend</module>
        <module>ui.apps</module>
        <module>ui.apps.structure</module>
        <module>ui.content</module> 
    </modules>
    
    
    <!-- proj1 Dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.proj1</groupId>
                <artifactId>proj1.ui.apps</artifactId>
                <type>zip</type>
                <version>0.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.proj1</groupId>
                <artifactId>proj1.core</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.0</version>
                <classifier>classic</classifier>
            </dependency>
            
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

when I run mvn clean install proj1 followed proj2 it works correctly in my local. proj2 is picking the dependency correctly.
If we run in our Azure Devops pipeline then proj2 is failing with following error message.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project proj2.ui.apps: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.proj2:proj2.ui.apps:content-package:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.proj1:proj1.ui.apps:zip:0.11.0 in https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of adobe-public-releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Is the proj2 build a whole separate pipeline?